# Ravendb versioning

Tags: ravendb

How to use ravendb versioning by asp.net MVC4. I'm new to both ravendb and asp.net MVC. I have to maintain all update and delete records(or) fields in the document. How it will be possible using ravendb. I want to maintain like audit table in RDBMS tables.

Comment: Have you read the [Raven DB documentation for the versioning bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/versioning)? It answers your questions.

Comment: I read that fully but still i need the working example and putting the dll in the server and client

Comment: Nobody here is going to do it for you. StackOverflow is for asking for advice when you get stuck. It doesn't sound like you're stuck yet.

Comment: Read the docs to learn how to set it up.  To get the audit trail back, use session.Advanced.GetRevisionsFor().  If you need something more elaborate, [try this instead](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-TemporalVersioning)

Comment: RE: the link provided by @shamp00, that link has moved [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/server/bundles/versioning).